# Creating a Utilities Class?

Tags: c#, oop, class, utilities

I'm very new to OOP and am trying my hardest to keep things strictly class based, while using good coding principles.

I'm a fair ways into my project now and I have a lot of general use methods I want to put into an utilities class.  Is there a best way to create a utilities class?

```
public class Utilities
{
    int test;

    public Utilities()
    {
    }

    public int sum(int number1, int number2)
    {
        test = number1 + number2;
    }
    return test;
}
```

After creating this Utilities class, do I just create an Utilities object, and run the methods of my choosing?   Do I have this Utilities class idea correct?

Comment: For public members it is recommended to have them camel-cased, like `Sum` instead of `sum`.

Comment: @Regent: who recommends that and where?  Just curious.

Comment: @BigJason: [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0.aspx).

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks!  I have never seen this before.

Comment: @Regent: Technically camel casing doesn't capitalize the first word, so "sum" would remain lowercase. "sumNumbers" if it was two words. "SumNumbers" is called pascal casing.

Comment: You know this code does not compile? You cannot use a return statement outside of a function. And also the constructor name does not match the type name..

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should make it a `static` class, like this:

```
public static class Utilities {
    public static int Sum(int number1, int number2) {
        return number1 + number2;
    }
}

int three = Utilities.Sum(1, 2);
```

The class should (usually) not have any fields or properties.  (Unless you want to share a single instance of some object across your code, in which case you can make a `static` read-only property.

Comment: Sigh gotta read the tags.  His example code would have compiled in Java ;)

Comment: Wherever it is meaningful, you can write extension methods. For extension methods, you can refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: @SB I think your previous example was correct. you'd just need to exchange 'final' for 'sealed' :)

Comment: Wouldn't be a single class responsible for utilities be a better separation of concerns instead of using extension methods?

Answer (score 14):

If you are working with .NET 3.0 or above, you should look into extension methods. They allow you to write a `static` function that will act against a particular type, like `Int32`, while seeming to be a method **on** that object. So then you could have: `int result = 1.Add(2);`.

Try this out; it might just show you another way. ;)

[C# Tutorial - Extension Methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20121113210820/http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-extension-methods)

Answer (score 4):

You will be better off using a `static` class with `static` methods.  Then you won't need to instantiate your utilities class to use it.  It will look something like this:

```
public static Utilites
{
  public static int sum(int number1, int number2)
  {
     test = number1+number2;
     return test;
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
int result = Utilites.sum(1, 3);
```

Comment: This is correct and the correct definition of a utilities class.

The other method is creating a utilities instance/object, which for your information (all of you) is not "wrong/bad" at all.
When a class needs to be instantiated to be useful, you might want a global utilities object.

An example of this is the Application object in Delphi and Lazarus.

Comment: True there are times it would be useful.  However in the case he showed us, adding two numbers, it made more sense to me to use `static` since there is no start-up cost every time you use the function.  If you were doing a lot of work, for example opening a database connection each time, then yeah instantiating a utilities class does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Best is to make the functions not reliable to members of a class. Therefore you can make the functions static.

Better is to make the functions an extension method of a type. [see here for example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

While new to OOP and trying to get a handle on best practices, it may be a good idea to try to avoid utility classes. You could redesign your class like

```
public class Sum
{
    private int _result;

    public int Result {
       get {
           return _result;
       }
    }

    public Sum(int startNum) {
        _results = startNum;
    }

    public void Add(int num) {
        _result += num;
    }
}
```

And is called like:

```
Sum sum = new Sum(1);
sum.add(2);
int result = sum.Result;
```

It'll be good practice until further experience with OOP can help you examine the trade-offs of using an utility class vs pure OOP principles.

Comment: `Sum` is a verb. It is more appropriate to create it as a method than as a class.

Comment: I disagree, while i have limited experience with OOP best practices, using static methods seems to be not unsensible - i'd prefer this than the above approach.

Answer (score -1):

yes this does not compile because  int test which is not supported inside static class either make it as static int test which will be supported and returns the output

Answer (score -1):

1. Create Utility class as public static class.
2. Defined Utility function-method with static keyword

Method Calling :-

int result = Utilities.sum(1, 2);

```
   public static class MyMath
         {
             int result;

             public static int sum(int number1, int number2)
             {
                 result= number1+number2;
                 return result;
             }
        }
```

Comment: Is this compilable? You have instance member in static class.

Answer (score -4):

do this.

```
public static class Utilities
{
    int test;

    public static int sum(int number1, int number2)
    {
        test = number1+number2;
        return test;
    }
}
```

That way you use it like

```
int result = Utilities.sum(1, 2);
```

Comment: This does not compile. You are attempting to access the instance variable `test` from a static method. There is no reason for `test` to be a class variable in this case either. At most it should be a local variable, at best you just write `return number1 + number2;`