# Static functions in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oop, webforms

I have an **asp.net webforms** application where the aspx pages get their data from a hierarchy of plain .net objects.

Currently the hierarchy is fully dynamic, being instantiated and stored once for each usersession, but I would like to use a function in one of the classes without creating the full hierarchy. (I want to avoid repeating the function that is in this class, but I need to use it outside the context of the class).

As an illustrative example, consider a webshop-type application with a shopping cart class. Inside the shopping cart class there is a function that applies discounts like say "buy 3 of this get 1 free". I want to be able to use this discount-function without creating a whole shopping cart and without repeating the code somewhere else.

Considering that this is a web-based application running under IIS7, which is the best approach?

Should I:

- Break out this function and put it in
  a separate class (containing only
  static helper functions)?
- Just make
  this one function static in the
  current class?
- Use some other
  approach to avoid the duplication?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like an Utility method. If it is, just create an Utils class.
Look at : [Creating An Utilities Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857832/creating-an-utilities-class)

Comment: I have a utilities class, but in this case it doesn't feel natural to put this code in there. It's not really a utility method. Then again it also feels wrong to call a class-specific function from the outside, and I am also worried what might happen once I have static methods in a class that's generated once per user.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I'm not exactly sure the best approach.  Would you be able to post a simplified version of your code?

It might make sense to create a base class that contains the function you need that all the other classes inherit from.

Comment: I didn't post any code because it would not really help in this case, I think the correct way to solve my particular problem will also be a kind of "best practice" in similar situations. I did however add an example to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: I understand what you mean. However, knowing a bit more about the objects themselves will help give a more appropriate answer.  For instance, if the method that you want to use on that one object doesn't logistically belong there, I would move it.  But if it relates to all of your objects, I might consider the base class.  Hope this helps.